# Is possible to clone complex visual object in MXML(flex)?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

```
function setLabel():void {
    var cloneObject = UtilFunctions.clone(t_1) as VBox;
    ticketList.push(cloneObject);
    tickets.addChild(cloneObject);
}
```

I am getting the t_1 id(id is a property of VBox) and I suppose that all he contains(all the child containers) also will be copied, and then save it into the array, and finally add it to some visual container, thus make a copy of some visual object, but that doesn't worked, so I am wondering if that is possible, the other solution that I think is to put it to the module and then dynamically create modules and add them to displayList, can you give me some hint? also which is more fast?

```
**UPDATE**

package library
{
 import flash.utils.describeType;
 import flash.utils.getDefinitionByName;
 import flash.utils.getQualifiedClassName;

 public class UtilFunctions
 {


     public static function newSibling(sourceObj:Object):* {
         if(sourceObj) {

             var objSibling:*;
             try {
                 var classOfSourceObj:Class = getDefinitionByName(getQualifiedClassName(sourceObj)) as Class;
                 objSibling = new classOfSourceObj();
             }

             catch(e:Object) {}

             return objSibling;
         }
         return null;
     }

     public static function clone(source:Object):Object {

         var clone:Object;
         if(source) {
             clone = newSibling(source);

             if(clone) {
                 copyData(source, clone);
             }
         }

         return clone;
     }

     public static function copyData(source:Object, destination:Object):void {

         //copies data from commonly named properties and getter/setter pairs
         if((source) && (destination)) {

             try {
                 var sourceInfo:XML = describeType(source);
                 var prop:XML;

                 for each(prop in sourceInfo.variable) {

                     if(destination.hasOwnProperty(prop.@name)) {
                         destination[prop.@name] = source[prop.@name];
                     }

                 }

                 for each(prop in sourceInfo.accessor) {
                     if(prop.@access == "readwrite") {
                         if(destination.hasOwnProperty(prop.@name)) {
                             destination[prop.@name] = source[prop.@name];
                         }

                     }
                 }
             }
             catch (err:Object) {
                 ;
             }
         }
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: Yes, in theory it should be possible.  There will be will most likely be some differences--such as the parent property.  You said it doesn't work; can you quantify that?  What doesn't work? Are you getting an error?

Comment: looks like I am using a wrong library to copy this complex object, thats' why it doesn't work, i've added the code of the copying object function, I can't find examples on how to do this in another way

Comment: You should just make your Views data-driven. If you supply the same data (or a copy) to a different instance of the same View Class, it should look exactly the same

Comment: what you mean by data-driven?